# How to power a class D amplifier with rechargeable batteries?

Tags: batteries, current, class-d

I am using a [TPA3136AD2PWPR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3136ad2.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1657657711220&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftpa3136ad2) to provide 5~6 W to an 8 ohm speakers.

According to the datasheet, I'll need to provide around 10~12V to the supply pins. I was hoping to use a rechargeable Li-Po battery to power the chip, so I thought of using a boost-convertor to step up the voltage from 3.7V to 12V.

Since I'm using batteries, current becomes an issue. I found some modules that can provide 12V/0.8A, but I doubt that's enough because even if all the 0.8A somehow went to the load, that would only provide 2.6 W to the speakers (0.8^2*8)/2.

- How do I find the current needed for the amplifier?
- How would you suggest I power the amplifier while using a rechargeable battery?

Comment: 12 V at 0.8 A is about 10 W. It seems to me that you have plenty of power available.

Comment: for DC, yes. but the signal going to the speakers will be AC. The RMS current now becomes 0.565A and RMS voltage 8.5V, or is that not how it works?

Comment: That is indeed not how it works.

Comment: You will need to be able to supply about 1.2A(rms) from your DC supply. Just try to look for one that can supply 1.2A DC maximum at the 12V nominal voltage ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into account the efficiency of the amplifier.
You said 5-6 W into 8\$\Omega\$ speakers, so assuming 2 speakers let's figure it for 12 W total.

The data sheet shows that at 12 W total output power and a 12 V supply the efficiency is going to be around 88%. So to find the power needed you would divide the output power by 0.88.

$$P_{supply} = \frac{12W}{0.88} = 13.63W $$

The maximum current would be
$$ \frac{13.63W}{12V} = 1.13A$$

That's how much current the amplifier should need to give you that output power. The output power is going to vary with volume, you might get away with a lower current supply if you keep the output lower, you may need a bit more on volume peaks. I would tend to add a bit of a safety margin and go for a bit higher current than calculated, 1.2 W to 1.5 W.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing batteries, run-time, speaker impedances, and must-have max-power levels are all tradeoffs with cost and efficiency and total power vs energy requirements in Watt-hours (A-h * Vavg)

> I thought of using a boost-convertor to step up the voltage from 3.7V to 12V.

This is definitely a bad idea unless you relax your power or runtime expectations significantly. Alternatively,  you need to make a booster with a much higher current drive capacity than you need to make it more efficient. Then you have to make that a soft start.

- Voltage boosters also raise the source impedance of the DC supply and make impulse currents (bass) lossier.  When you transform voltages up, battery currents go up as well.  If you start with lower impedance speakers like 4 Ohms and choose 2S2P for 7V then you can optimize for efficiency and improve power out.  But if you are stuck with 8 Ohms and limit your budget to 2 cells 2S is better than 2P with a voltage doubler with the lowest ESR.

But if you demand that extra power from 3W to 10W with 8-ohm speakers, then you need 4S and can expect a much shorter run time using that extra power.
[image]
[image]

If efficiency is a priority, choose 90%, and choose a battery voltage and Wh to match your expected usage. If you use much less power than this maximum, efficiency suffers and then runtime in hours might not be what you expect.

Either way, your budget is a key factor to achieve your TBD goals.

The latter question on computing current is Iin=Pin/Vin= Pout/Vout/Effic.  This does not include battery ESR losses and [Peukert's Law](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Peukert%27s_law) for Lithium cells inefficiencies of Ah actual vs 20h rating. This means you will not get the full rated Ah when consumed far less than 20h but "something less".

If max power and budget rank higher than runtime, then choose 4 Ohms speakers for 2S vs 3S or 4S. Then Parallel (P) for more runtime.

In the end, it is a matter of your priorities, then expectations, or "specs" then choices by calculations.